# IRC auto respond bot not responding

Tags: java, irc

I am writing a bot in java for my IRC.
I have it joining, self authenticating, and showing the messages in the bots window so it can see that chatter. BUT it wont respond like i want.

```
import java.io.*;

import java.net.*;



public class TwmlBot {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        String server = "example.com";

        String nick = "TWML_Bot";

        String login = "TWML_Bot";

        String passwd = "examplepassword";

        String channel = "#welcome";


        Socket socket = new Socket(server, 6667);

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(

                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream( )));

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(

                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream( )));


        writer.write("NICK " + nick + "\r\n");

        writer.write("USER " + login + " 8 * : Java IRC Bot\r\n");

        writer.flush( );


        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {

            if (line.indexOf("004") >= 0) {.

                break;

            }

            else if (line.indexOf("433") >= 0) {

                System.out.println("Nickname is already in use.");

                return;

            }

        }


        writer.write("JOIN " + channel + "\r\n");

        writer.write("identify " + passwd + "\r\n");

        writer.flush( );


        while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {

            if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("PING ")) {

                writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");

                System.out.println(line);

                writer.flush( );

            }

            else {

                System.out.println(line);

            }

        }

    }



}
```

Basically if a user messages ping in chat i want the bot to respond with pong.

I'm fairly new to java and this is just a simple bot to try to learn java. Like I said I have it joining my IRC and logging in but it don't respond to chat.

No errors in compiling and no errors while running.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need to check if somebody sends a `PRIVMSG`, and respond to that.

Comment: I cant figure that out, i tried it with the following and it didnt work... writer.write("PRIVMSG " + channel + " hello world \r\n");   -- doesnt seem to work

Comment: @Twml Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: @Progman added my full source

Comment: @Twml Add a `System.out.println(line);` statement inside your `while` loops to see the message you have received from the server. Please [edit] your question to include the new source code and the output you get.

Comment: added ``` System.out.println(line); ``` inside while loop with the ping/pong lines, nothing new compiling running or doing /privmsg /query or chatting normally no response from bot.

Comment: Are you sure the line would Start with PING?  If there's as much as one character before that, your test will also fail.

Comment: @Twml Put the `System.out.println(line);` at the top of the `while` blocks to see every message received, not just in case a PING is received. And add the `System.out.println(line);` line in both `while` loops. Also add several debug `println()` statements to see where you are in your code to follow the code execution. Add the new source code you have to your question and include the output you get from the execution.

Comment: You should have a look at the [IRC RFC section](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459#section-4.4) related to how messages work. It's pretty much the same whether it's a private message or a channel message. But it will never start by `PING` as the format looks something like `PRIVMSG user :Message sent`

Comment: @Twml, Is this issue still relevant, if so can you edit the post to reflect what exactly is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing a **lower case** String to the String `"PING"`:

`line.toLowerCase().startsWith("PING ")`

This is guaranteed to return false.

Maybe you've meant `toUpperCase()`?

Comment: changing toUpperCase() does nothing also, no response from bot still. what im looking to do is if a users message starts with ping PiNg or PING the bot responds with pong